# ToggleButton siempre seleccionado

Tags: javafx

Quiero que un grupo de `ToggleButon` se comporte como un grupo de `RadioButton`, es decir, que siempre haya una opción seleccionada. Desconozco si hay algún método que lo haga directamente o, por el contrario, tengo que programarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos formas de hacerlo: o bien creas un grupo de `RadioButton` y los tuneas con CSS o bien interceptas el intento de dejar deseleccionados los `ToggleButton` y los modificas según tu conveniencia.

La forma fácil es la segunda. Aquí te dejo un pequeño ejemplo:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ToggleSiempreSeleccionado extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ToggleButton Opción1 = new ToggleButton("Opción 1");
        ToggleButton Opción2 = new ToggleButton("Opción 2");

        ToggleGroup grupoOpciones = new ToggleGroup();
        grupoOpciones.getToggles().addAll(Opción1, Opción2);

        HBox contenedorRaíz = new HBox();       
        contenedorRaíz.getChildren().addAll(Opción1, Opción2);
        contenedorRaíz.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        contenedorRaíz.setSpacing(10);

        Scene escena = new Scene(contenedorRaíz, 180, 50);

        primaryStage.setScene(escena);
        primaryStage.show();

        grupoOpciones.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(
            (ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> arg0, Toggle valorAnterior, Toggle valorNuevo) -> {
                if (grupoOpciones.getToggles().indexOf(grupoOpciones.getSelectedToggle()) == -1) {                
                    grupoOpciones.selectToggle(valorAnterior);
                }
            }
        );     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```